# Do not add an item to a session array if it already exists

Tags: php, session

Hi I am a bit of a newbie here - so please bear with me.
I am trying to create a WishList - similar to a shopping cart but without the payment gateway. Anyway.

I have the following code which adds an item to an array when the Add to Wishlist button is clicked

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
  $ITEM = array(    
    'name' => $_GET['add']      
  );

  $_SESSION['WISH_LIST'][] =  $ITEM;
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

I want to make it work so that the item is not added if it is already there.

I tried this

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])){
  $ITEM = array(    
    'name' => $_GET['add']      
  );

  if ( in_array($_GET['add'], $ITEM) ) {
    echo "Already Added";
  } else {
    $_SESSION['WISH_LIST'][] =  $ITEM;
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  } 
}
```

But this never adds the item - I always get the 'Already Added' text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check what exists in the session, not the $ITEMS array:

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $ITEM = array(
        'name' => $_GET['add']
    );

    if (in_array($ITEM, $_SESSION['WISH_LIST'])) {
        echo "Already Added";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['WISH_LIST'][] = $ITEM;
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
}
```

It might be nicer to indent your code, too.

Comment: in_array() takes the needle argument first, so `in_array($ITEM, $_SESSION['WISH_LIST'])`

Comment: ah yes, you're correct. Didn't spot that. Will edit.